# How to kill Python program from Test class using 'unittest'?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking, automated-tests

I have created a few test classes using "unittest" package to my Python app.
In this app, there is a step that the user inserts a path to excel file (from the GUI) and I want to test some cases about this input file.

**In my test class**, I want to **kill** the program if the user inserts the wrong input (and verifies that exception was thrown).

The problem begins because:
The behavior of the program is to open a pop-up window (represents the error) and return to the **main menu**.

So, what is the way to stop my program (from test class) after the pop-up window was opened?
I'm thinking to use tearDown, but I need some advice to kill the program and **not continue to the main menu.**

Comment: Please try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), otherwise it is difficult to understand what exactly you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i'm wrong, I dont know much about this, but I believe `exit()` will work if you put it within the exception condition. Hope I was able to help!